# How to create a .txt file in a specific directory in Android?

Tags: android, file, export

I am trying to develop a program which creates a file in a specific directory (.txt file) and stores some data in it (Strings for example). I also want that the file can be accessed by the user (If I go to file explorer I can view the file I've created and maybe edit it with another program or something).

I've tried many things, but I cant manage this to work.

Here is the code I am using atm:

```
public void createFile(View view) throws IOException {

  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd");
    Date now = new Date();
    String fileName = formatter.format(now) + ".txt";
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Sonda Drive Test";

    File mypath = new File(filepath);
    if(!mypath.exists()) {
        mypath.mkdir();
    }
    //now the mkdir returns true isntead of false


    File myfile = new File(mypath, fileName);

    try{
        if(!myfile.exists()){
            txtDebug.setText("Não existe ficheiro!");
            myfile.createNewFile();
        }
        else{
            txtDebug.setText("Já existe ficheiro!");
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        txtDebug.setText("Erro!");
    }
}
```

I've also added the permissions bellow:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The problem is that when I do

```
myfile.createNewFile();
```

The application stops and closes.. But if I comment that line, it also won't create any file...

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I Manage to make this work for API 22. How can i do it for API 25?

Comment: `The program Crashes` what exactly do you mean by this? What do you get for an exception / stacktrace? Please [edit] int the details log output from LogCat. Voting to close for lack of context.

Comment: `mypath.mkdir();`. Check the return value as it might fail to create the directory. If it returns false then display a toast to the user saying so and return.

Comment: You might get this crash because the "myfile" don't exists, you need to check if the file exists if (!myfile.exists())

Comment: Of course the file  does not exist. OP tries to create one. Wrong advice!

Comment: @MattClark edited.

Comment: @greenapps can you please explain me how to fix it please?

Comment: You have edited nothing helpful... Please provide the log messages you get when the crash occurs.

Comment: `explain me how to fix it please`?? I explained you what to do exactly. So what is the problem? Cant you check a return value? Or displsy a toast? Unclear.

Comment: @RakshitNawani i've tried that, but it still dont work.

Comment: Have you ever checked if that directory is created? With a file explorer app on your device?

Comment: @MattClark it just says: "myAPP Stopped". And i cant see any error messages in debug

Comment: LogCat is the ADB tool that prints all log messages from your phone. When the application crashes, there **will be a log message**. Edit in this contents.

Comment: Please add these to the pots body and not spread out amongst 5 comments.

Comment: @greenapps

I do. I did that, **mypath.mkdir()** returns false. I also displayed a Toast alerting user. But i cant understand how will it solve this...

Comment: @MattClark I am sorry, this is my first post ever here. I've edited it.

Comment: `mypath.mkdir() returns false. I also displayed a Toast`. Then edit your post and add the code so we see what you do. And tell us android version of app and device.

Comment: `application stops and closes..`. That cannot be caused by the code you posted. Probably later when you try to use myfile. You should put a toast in that catch block too and return. Adapt your code and show us. The logcat lines you posted have nothing to do with a crash.

Comment: `added the permissions bellow:`. Ok. But outside `<application>` tag?

Comment: @greenapps alright, i will edit my last code version.
I manage to find the bug in it. If i change my API version to 22 in the build.gradle (I was using 25), it works fine.
How does it not work for API 25?

Comment: @greenapps yes, they were outside.

Comment: You have to ask the user for runtime permissions too then.

Comment: @greenapps exactly, thats what i did. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

you are putting the mypath as the path but you define the mypath as file

Comment: Ok, so how do i define mypath as a path then?

Comment: Bruno dont listen to Bruno.